# Custom-defined type highlighting in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, clang++

I am looking for a configuration/combination of plugins + clang (or any other parser) that can allow sublime text to highlight all custom defined types just like it highlights native types such as int, double, char, etc. More specifically I guess the exact implementation would be to traverse all included files (both custom written ones and compiled libraries) and find the names of all defined `class`es, `struct`s and `typedef`s and highlight them as types in the rest of the source code.

Do similar configurations exist for other languages such as python, javascript, java?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145265/sublime-text-c-highlight/23198103#23198103](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145265/sublime-text-c-highlight/23198103#23198103) but the answer there would seem to achieve what you want by a slightly different path.

Comment: Thanks, that can work as a temporary solution, but it requires that a specific naming convention is followed which is not always the case. Any idea whether a configuration such as the one I am asking for exists at all?

Comment: I don't know of anything like that and, given the way ST syntax highlighting works,  I don't see a **practical** way to achieve what you appear to be describing. I can think of a way to do it but it would bring more problems than it solves. Perhaps someone smarter than me will come up with something.