# Sublime Text 4: How to highlight C++ class/struct names and typedef, using and #define aliases?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext4

I want the C++ STL data structures, as well as my self-defined classes/structs and aliases, to be highlighted as a primitive type like `int` or `double`, in a different color.

In particular, I want these to be highlighted:

```cpp
using int64 = long long;
#define pb push_back

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int64> a = {1,2,3}; // hightlight std::vector and int64.
    a.pb(5) // highlight pb.      

    return 0;
}
```

I have already found this post: [Sublime Text - C++ Highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145265/sublime-text-c-highlight)

But when I tried to do the similar things to the accepted answer in the post, where they said that I should install `Package Control`, then `PackageResourcesViewer`, then choose `Open Resources -> C++ -> C++.tmLanguage`, in Sublime Text 4, I could not find any files with such name.

So, how can I reach my goal?